# How to append numbers an undefined amount of time to new variables [Java]

Tags: java, for-loop, boolean, append

I have made a working card game based on the car game War. It works great as it is but I made it around the idea of only two players. In order for the program to determine the cards drawn and their value, I made a bunch of booleans to check if a string was a certain card so I could then assign the value afterwards.

```
                boolean checkAce = deckList.get(0).startsWith("Ace");
                boolean checkTwo = deckList.get(0).startsWith("Two");
                boolean checkThree = deckList.get(0).startsWith("Three");
                boolean checkFour = deckList.get(0).startsWith("Four");
                boolean checkFive = deckList.get(0).startsWith("Five");
                boolean checkSix = deckList.get(0).startsWith("Six");
                boolean checkSeven = deckList.get(0).startsWith("Seven");
                boolean checkEight = deckList.get(0).startsWith("Eight");
                boolean checkNine = deckList.get(0).startsWith("Nine");
                boolean checkTen = deckList.get(0).startsWith("Ten");
                boolean checkJack = deckList.get(0).startsWith("Jack");
                boolean checkQueen = deckList.get(0).startsWith("Queen");
                boolean checkKing = deckList.get(0).startsWith("King");
```

Then whichever boolean becomes true would assign a certain value so that it could be compared to the second player. So I have this code twice for each person.

My dilemma now is that I need to modify it to work with multiple players that are determined after the program starts by a user prompt. After some thought, I determined to only way, if possible, to get that to work without completely rewriting it would be if I could set a for loop to run the amount of times as there are playing.

For that to work, I would need to be able to append a number next to each boolean (P1, P2, P3, etc.) so it would read `checkAceP3`. But I'm not sure if there is a function that would allow that. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you clarify on how you're coming between the first and second player?

Comment: How players will play your game? How did you design the game?

Comment: I initially had two of the above blocks of code in my question. `checkAce` and `checkAceP2`. And then I would run the logic for both separately and assign them scores to their `playerOneScore` and `playerTwoScore` variables respectively. Would there by any way, like a for loop, that would let me do this once in a method and apply the scores to a non static amount of players?

Comment: @fuzzy28 thats the thing. I designed the game around two players. But I now need it to work with any number of players and that player amount is chosen by the user at the start of the program.

Comment: But how will they play the game? is this a stand-alone application? Do they have a separate client application talking to a server?

Comment: @fuzzy28 Sorry I should have been more clear. This isn't a real game. I'm new to programming and this is an assignment for a class I'm in. The entire "game" lives within the console and each player just presses enter on their turn and the console tells them what card they drew and what points they got and then tells the winner until all the cards are gone .

Comment: Why don't you create a List of Cards in an ArrayList, when player1 turned and pick Ace of diamond. Remove it from the ArrayList, with this you are not tied with how many players will play your game. Is this what you want?

Comment: @fuzzy28 My main issue at this point is that I need int variables to assign each players score to so I can compare them and call a winner. I'm not sure how to do this without predefining playerOneScore, playerTwoScore, playerThreeScore, etc. for every possible amount of players. I know that seems impractical so I want to know if there is a way to automate this based on how many players are going to be playing each round.

Comment: @andrewxt Have you tried asking the user how many players there are before starting the game, then assigning this value to the size of an array?

Comment: Create a HashMap of players with String,Integer key-value pairs, where key String is the player name and the Integer value will be the score. Iterate through the keys for every turn.

Comment: I haven't heard of HashMap before but I will do some research to see if it will help solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @fuzzy28 not entirely sure that would work as this program uses an entire deck of cards and draws one for each player and calculates a score each round. And this happens as many times until the deck array reaches 0.

Comment: You mean 1 player = 52 cards?, HashMap would work for scoring purposes

Comment: @fuzzy28 I'm sorry. Thank you so much for your help so far. I think I got a general idea of how the HashMap works but I'm confused on how to actually implement it. Can you post an example just to get me started?

Answer (score 0):

You should define the player logic in a `class Player`. This way, you can create as many instances of player as you want. Each of them will have their own copy of all your variables.

For example, you define a Player class like this:

```
class Player {
     String _name;
     int _score; 
}
```

And then you can define as many players as you want at runtime:

```
List<Player> _playerList = new ArrayList();
_playerList.add(new Player("player1"));
_playerList.add(new Player("player2"));
_playerList.add(new Player("player3"));
...

boolean gameOver = false;

// play your game
while (!gameOver) {
    for (Player player : _playerList) {
        player.playTurn();
        if (gameOver()) {
             gameOver = true;
             break;
        }
    }
}

// loop through the players and determine the winner
for (Player player : _playerList) {
     ...
}
```